# I extendedly removed apt package manager, how to fix?

Tags: apt

I have removed `apt` as I was removing keyring with the Synaptic Package Manager.

```
Removed the following ESSENTIAL packages: apt

Completely removed the following packages: ubuntu-keyring

Removed the following packages: apt-utils unattended-upgrades
```

How to fix this?

---

Thanks for the reply

```
(Reading database ... 186695 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apt_1.2.15ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt (1.2.15ubuntu0.2) over (1.2.15ubuntu0.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
 apt depends on ubuntu-keyring; however:
  Package ubuntu-keyring is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**0.4 loki**

You can download the package `apt` 
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.2.15ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb

and install via the command line

```
sudo dpkg --install ~/Downloads/apt_1.2.15ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
```